# Capitalisation of uncle and aunt in phrases like 'your U/uncle Bill'

Tags: capitalization

I came across this e card:

[image: []()]

and the capitalisation of "uncle" just somehow disturbed me. To the point where I googled the capitalisation of "aunt" and "uncle" and I found [this GrammarBook article](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/capitalization/kinship-names-to-capitalize-or-not-to-capitalize/) by Jane Straus which seems to suggest that after "your" uncle is not capitalised.

It would be ironic if the person making fun of capitalisation couldn't get it right themselves. However, further googling yielded some contradicting results.

Hence my question is:

> To capitalise or not to capitalise 'Uncle' etc (after your)?

Comment: It's capitalized for the sake of the pun. See [jack off](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Jack+Off).

Comment: @Yay That's not the point here, I'm afraid.

Comment: @NVZ How come? According to the link provided, it shouldn't be capitalized, but the rule for capitalizing kinship names is stretched a little here to make the pun clearer. Maybe, the pun would have been better if only Jack had been capitalized, but I don't think the rule for capitalizing kinship names in this case is [clear-cut](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=your+Aunt%2C+your+Uncle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyour%20Aunt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyour%20Uncle%3B%2Cc0) anyway.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Duplicate, perhaps. But here OP asked whether this ecard has made a mistake by using *your Uncle* instead of *your uncle.*

Comment: If you refer to the sibling of your parent as "Uncle Jack" then it's capitalized.  If he is your "uncle, Jack", then it's not capitalized.

Comment: @Hot Licks Adding the comma makes it a lot easier, but there are style gurus allowing _his uncle Jack_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - The comma is "optional", but conceptualizing it's presence helps with the decision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The website http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2014/11/aunt-uncle.html says that the distinction is a matter of style, not grammar.

In the article, it quotes the Chicago Manual of Style, which seems to support the notion that in the phrase "**your uncle Jack**," **uncle** is not capitalized.  But many people find fault with the CMOS, so you are free not to heed its dicta.

The site http://grammartips.homestead.com/betty.html makes an interesting distinction:

> What about "her aunt Betty"? Well, that depends--if you mean "Aunt" as
>   part of Betty's "name," then write "her Aunt Betty"; but if you mean
>   it the same way you'd say "her sister Betty," then don't capitalize
>   the word.

But a Google Ngram of **my aunt Betty** vs. **my Aunt Betty** shows the latter more popular by a margin of about 2.5 to 1.

I personally would capitalize.  To me, because most people call their aunts named Betty "Aunt Betty," aunt should be considered part of the name.  Not so necessarily with other kinship words like **sister** or **cousin**, as mentioned above.

But ultimately, it's a matter of style.  So I doubt you can reasonably say the e-card is incorrect; it would make just as much sense, though, if it said **uncle Jack**.

Comment: This answer adds significantly to those at the former question.

Comment: I've just remembered a quote from the Western _Sabata_ : 'I'm sorry ... Your Father Brown has just died from a coffin' fit.' You're quite right: _part of the title or not_?